# Telling steam my game is 64 bit

Tags: unity, steam, macos, build-process, deployment

I'm finally done making my game and am almost done putting it on steam (just need to wait for the build to approve). But I've noticed that on the store it says "Notice: This product is not compatible with macOS 10.15 Catalina or above."

I believe this is because steam thinks that the game is a 32bit game. But I'm on Catalina 10.15.5 and I can play the game. So is there a way to tell steam that the game *is* 64bit?

Or is my game somehow *not* 64bit. How do I know?

EDIT: One other thing I just realized is that the store gave this notice BEFORE I even uploaded a build. So it must have just decided based on something else.

It's just a small pixel art game that's 24mbs and I made it on Unity building for PC, Mac, and linux standalone. Here are my build settings:

[image: Unity build settings]

Comment: Unity Version: 2020.1.4f1

Comment: One other thing to note is that the store gave this notice BEFORE I even uploaded a build. So it must have just decided based on something else.

Comment: Is your depot configured for 64-bit or 32-bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this isn't a problem on the development side, but rather a problem with the Steam client failing to correctly identify your OS.

Taken from a Steamworks announcement regarding [configuring Steam client to detect 64 bit MacOS](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/announcements/detail/3632639303428097613):

> If your Mac application already supports 64-bit, please login to
> Steamworks and select the macOS -> 64 Bit Binaries Included check box
> in the Supported Operating Systems section for your application. This
> will ensure that your macOS app will appear as compatible for users
> who are running Steam on macOS 10.15.

Comment: Yep that seems to be the problem. Thanks!